# Using Javascript to dynamically create dom elements with incrementing ID's

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a div with an ID  "orangeButton"  and each time you click on it it creates a new div. This works fine but... I want each newly created div to have an incremental number added to it's ID.

I am not sure how to do this.

Here is a fiddle of the code I have thus far with comments.

http://jsfiddle.net/taoist/yPrab/1/

Thank you

**Javascript Code**

```
   var applicationArea = document.getElementById("applicationArea");
    var orangeButton = document.getElementById("orangeButton");


    orangeButton.onclick = function() {
      var newDivThingy = document.createElement("div");
      newDivThingy.id  = 'newDivThingy';  // I want each newly created div to have a      numeric value concatenated to it's ID. IE newDivThingy1 newDivThingy2 newDivThingy3
      applicationArea.appendChild(newDivThingy);


    };​
```

Comment: Just keep a variable `var index = 0;` and do `newDivThingy.id  = 'newDivThingy' + (index++);`.

Comment: are you willing to use jquery?

Comment: No JQuery. I prefer to stick to raw Javascript for my own learning purposes. Felix seems like he has the answer I'm looking for. Will try it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Am I missing something, why not use a counter?

```
var counter = 0;
button.onclick = function(){
   var newDivThingy = document.createElement("div");
   newDivThingy.id  = 'newDivThingy' + (++counter);
   // continue your stuff here     
}
```

Comment: I tried playing with different ways to create a counter and couldn't figure out the proper syntax. I decided to ask instead of waste time.

Comment: @Taoist, Cool. Play with ++counter and counter++ to start from 0 or 1 for the <div> ID. I'd keep the initial counter at 0, that way it reflects current number of created items. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Libraries like underscorejs provide a uniqueid function for this.  Otherwise its easy to implement one.

```
myNamespace.uniqueId = (function () {
    var counter = 0; // in closure
    return function (prefix) {
        counter++;
        return (prefix || '') + '-' + counter; 
    };
}());
```

Usage.

```
newDiv.id = myNamespace.uniqueId('newDiv');
```

Comment: This looks cool. Just wondering... Is a `return function(){....}` making a copy of the function each time?

Comment: @AlexisWilke No, because the self executing function fires once.  The result is uniqueId is assigned function (prefix) { ...  having the counter variable in a closure (and its own private scope)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a integer and increment it as each element is added.

```
var applicationArea = document.getElementById("applicationArea"),
    orangeButton = document.getElementById("orangeButton"),
    counter = 1;

orangeButton.onclick = function() {
    var newDivThingy = document.createElement("div");
        newDivThingy.id = "newDivThingy" + counter++;
    applicationArea.appendChild(newDivThingy);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no doubt you have solution and may have forgotten this post.
BUT, I wold like to show a solution that is a compact format.

Note the counter is set to (counter++) so it will start at 1.

```
var orangeButton = document.getElementById("orangeButton");
var counter = 0;
  orangeButton.onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('applicationArea')
    .appendChild(document.createElement('div'))
    .setAttribute("id", 'newDivThingy' + counter++);
  // I want each newly created div to have a
  // numeric value concatenated to it's ID.
  // IE newDivThingy1 newDivThingy2 newDivThingy3
  };​
```