# Javascript reusing forms

Tags: javascript

I want to get the names of the n (say n==5) children of a given person, by using the same form each time.
I can't seem to be able to produce javascript code that will accomplish this simple task.

```
for (var i = 0; i<5; i++){
<form id="child_form">
  Child name:
  <input type="text" id="child_name" name="child_nm" size="40">
  <br>
  <input type="button"  value="Submit" onclick="myFunction()">
</form>
}

<script language="javascript">

<script>
function myFunction() {
add_child_to_array();
}

var array_of_children = []; 
function add_child_to_array(){
var input_string = document.getElementById("child_name").value;
alert(input_string);
array_of_inputs.push(input_string);
}
</script>
```

But clearly one can't do that.

I've tried taking the data out of the form and then resetting the form.  It turns out you can do either but not both.

I haven't found a website that deals with this problem.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking how to do a repeating loop that dynamically generates the HTML?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Javascript to dynamically create dom elements with incrementing ID's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107817/using-javascript-to-dynamically-create-dom-elements-with-incrementing-ids)

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly a bit of a mess. Assuming I understand correctly, you need to create the form in javascript, so it can be dynamically added as many times as you want. I have written a generalised way of doing this. You may want to change / simplify it. I have made sure all elements are dynamic so that can be accessed properly. Also, I have used JQuery which I highly suggest.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){

            var allForms = document.getElementById("all-forms");

            for(var i = 0;i<5;i++){
                 form = document.createElement("div");
                 form.id = "form-" + i.toString();
                 if(i!=0){
                    form.style.display = "none";
                 }
                 input = document.createElement("input");
                 input.id = "child_name"+i;
                 input.placeholder = "input"+i;
                 submit = document.createElement("button");
                 submit.innerHTML = "go"+i;
                 submit.id = "submit-"+i;
                 submit.className = "buttons";
                 form.appendChild(input);
                 form.appendChild(submit);
                 allForms.appendChild(form);


            }

            $(".buttons").click(function(){
                var id = $(this).attr("id").substring(7);
                $("#form-"+id).hide();
                var nextID = (parseInt(id)+1).toString();
                $("#form-"+nextID).show();
            });

          });

    </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id = "all-forms"></div>


 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Caspar, Your answer seems very clever, except the code doesn't work for me.  .Firebug gives the error: TypeError: allForms is null
 .appendChild(form);
, but that's becauseI 'm inexperienced

Comment: I meant to say: "I don't see why, but that's because I'm inexperienced."

Comment: But how does one make each form show up one at a time?  I tried   putting allForms.removeChild(form); in myFunction but no go.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options to accomplish this task. I would prefer to use the HTML5 [template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) element functionality.

You could alternatively [create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) the DOM Elements by yourself.

Comment: When did i mention jQuery?

Comment: var theForm = document.getElementById('theform');
allForms.removeChild(theForm);

Comment: I seem to be sending comments before I can complete them.  I've added var theForm = document.getElementById('theform');
allForms.removeChild(theForm);
to myFunction, where for convenience I've now given the forms the id="theform".  This nicely removes each of the forms as it's completed but I can't seem to make the forms originally show up only one at a time. Continued thanks.